# Symbolic Links as include folders in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, symlink

My folder structure is something like this:

```
.
└─ Projects
   ├─ MyProject
   |  ├─ lib
   |  ├─ src
   |  └─ include
   └─ MyOtherProject
      ├─ src
      └─ include
```

I need the headers from `MyOtherProject` in `MyProject` and I created a symbolic link with the following command `mklink /D "Projects/MyProject/include/MyOtherProject" "Projects/MyOtherProject/include"` but when using Visual Studio it doesn't recognize `MyOtherProject` folder in the include directory.

I have set up the `Additional Include Directories` variable in VS as `$(ProjectDir)include` which should evaluate to `Projects/MyProject/include`.

As to my question I think it is, does Visual Studio support using symbolic links and if so what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using forward slashes in `mklink /D "Projects/MyProject/include/MyOtherProject" "Projects/MyOtherProject/include"` - use backslashes and test created link in explorer.

When creating symbolic links, you have to think about target relative to link directory. `mklink /D "Projects\MyProject\include" "..\MyOtherProject\include"` or give full absolute path.

In my opinion directory junction (`mklink /j "MyProject\include" "MyOtherProject\include"`) are easier to work with. I'm using them for redirecting directories used by Firefox, Thunderbird and other programs.

For additional includes I would use just `include`. You can even use `..\MyOtherProject\include` directly without symlink or junction.

Comment: Tested it using forward and backward slashes. I also tried with relative and absolute paths. I even tested it using `/J` insted of `/D` and restarting VS after creating the link but still nothing. The symlink is created just fine but VS doesn't understand it for whatever reason.

Comment: Just tested to include a header with an absolute path to the symlinked include directory and it seems to work so I'm guessing it is a problem with the `Additional Include Libraries`. Also yes, for a smaller project I could use relative include paths as you pointed out, but I don't think that it would scale well for bigger projects (I could be wrong) and it is not what the question was about.

Comment: I have checked with VS2013 and it works. Junctions are very reliable and transparent for most programs. In your case to create junction `cd` to `Projects` directory and `mklink /j "MyProject\include" "MyOtherProject\include"`. Remember to delete first `MyProject\include`. If created link works as expected in explorer, then probably your VS project is misconfigured.

Comment: Just checked with a fresh new project on VS2017 with only changing the `Additional Include Libraries` and it does not work.

Comment: `Additional Include Directories`

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: Reinstalled VS2017 and it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help.